# Two condition filtering and removing Zero Values

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, tidyverse, remove-if

I have a simple [dataframe](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2tlfz5d5kr0h5mj/Anaheim.csv?dl=0) of counts in a growing pepper experiment. I want to remove observations where both `treatment's`[(Control and Covered) `Fruit_total` are equal to zero. I tried `filter` but I can only handle one variable at a time. Any advice?

[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6oBK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by grouping on `location.id` and filtering for the sum of `Fruit_total`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(location.ID) %>%
  filter(sum(Fruit_total) != 0)
```

Yields:

```
# A tibble: 22 x 5
# Groups:   location.ID [11]
   location.ID  Year plant                 treatment Fruit_total
         <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                 <chr>           <dbl>
 1           7  2019 Anaheim.Peppers.Count Control            23
 2           9  2019 Anaheim.Peppers.Count Control             3
 3          15  2019 Anaheim.Peppers.Count Control             0
 4          23  2019 Anaheim.Peppers.Count Control             1
 5          38  2019 Anaheim.Peppers.Count Control             8
 6          41  2019 Anaheim.Peppers.Count Control             1
 7          42  2019 Anaheim.Peppers.Count Control            12
 8          43  2019 Anaheim.Peppers.Count Control             7
 9          45  2019 Anaheim.Peppers.Count Control             5
10          49  2019 Anaheim.Peppers.Count Control            13
# ... with 12 more rows
```